# Keras wrong accuracy using model.predict

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am using this code for a CNN

```
train_batches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory('dice_sklearn/train', target_size=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT),
                                        classes=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'],
                                        batch_size=cv_opt['batch'],
                                        color_mode="grayscale")

test_batches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory('dice_sklearn/test', target_size=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT),
                                       class_mode='categorical',
                                       batch_size=cv_opt['batch'],
                                       shuffle=False)
train_num = len(train_batches)
test_num = len(test_batches)

model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, 1)),
    Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    Dropout(0.30),

    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    Dropout(0.30),

    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    Dropout(0.30),

    Flatten(),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.5),
    Dense(6, activation='softmax'),

])
print(model.summary())

model.compile(Adam(lr=cv_opt['lr']), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(train_batches, steps_per_epoch=train_num,
                              epochs=cv_opt['epoch'], verbose=2)

model.save('cnn-keras.h5')

test_batches.reset()
prediction = model.predict(test_batches, steps=test_num, verbose=1)
predicted_class = np.argmax(prediction, axis=1)
classes = test_batches.classes[test_batches.index_array]
accuracy = (predicted_class == classes).mean()
print("Final accuracy:", accuracy * 100)
```

Where

- cv_opt['batch'] is set to 50
- cv_opt['lr'] is set to 0.0003
- cv_opt['epoch'] is set to 50

The output from the training phase (with model.fit) on the last line (last epoch) returns:

```
192/192 [==============================] - 98s 510ms/step - loss: 0.0514 - accuracy: 0.9818 - val_loss: 0.0369 - val_accuracy: 0.9833
```

But when I run this part of code:

```
test_batches.reset()
prediction = model.predict(test_batches, steps=test_num, verbose=1)
predicted_class = np.argmax(prediction, axis=1)
classes = test_batches.classes[test_batches.index_array]
accuracy = (predicted_class == classes).mean()
print("Final accuracy:", accuracy * 100)
```

I get an accuracy score very very low: (0.16).
But if a plot the learning curves I can see that the test/validation curve (if in testing or in parameter tuning) both reach accuracies near 90%.

Am I using the model.predict in the wrong way?

Comment: No, the problem is that using generator.classes is not reliable since the generator has a state and might not match the order in generator.classes, you should iterate on the generator to get both inputs and targets in order to compute any metric, just how model.evaluate works.

Comment: I had a similar and very weird error long back, can u try to remove the validation split from the model.fit and then try validation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your model is not overfitting. Steps 1 and 2 do not have to be implemented at all in order to solve your problem. In fact, it is even more wrong since the author states that in case of overfitting you need to add more layers, which is strongly advised against: when one has an overfitting model, the model needs to be made simpler, not more complex.

The solution to your issue lies in @Dr.Snoopy's answer : the order of the classes do not match.

My recommendation is to iterate manually through the entire test set, get the ground truth, get the prediction (ensure the same exact preprocessing on images like in the training set is applied on your test set images) before you feed them to your model.

Then, calculate your metrics. This will solve your problem.

For example, you could use the idea below:

```
    correctly_predicted = 0
    for image in os.scandir(path_to_my_test_directory):
        image_path = image.path
        image = cv2.imread(image_path)
        image = apply_the_same_preprocessing_like_in_training(image)
        #transform from (H,W,3) to (1,H,W,3) because TF + Keras predict only on batches
        image = np.expand_dims(image,axis=0)
        prediction_label = np.argmax(model.predict(image))
        if prediction_label == ground_truth_label:
              correctly_predicted+=1
```

Comment: Adding more layers don't make your model complex, makes your model deeper. The possible problem could be vanishing gradient. Use correct terminologies even if you are going to attack me

Comment: Sorry, but making the model deeper indeed makes it more complex. The opposite of shallow/less complex is indeed deep and more complex.  At the same time, I do not think that bringing arguments which uphold the truth in this situation means attacking you. Indeed your suggestions were misleading, because overfitting is definitely not solved by stacking more layers in the network. I did not even downvote your comment, but you can see the reaction of other people to it. Please understand that this is not a competition, but should be healthy conversation which should bring the truth/solution.

Comment: In addition, neither does switching from Adam to AdaDelta help at all.